# android 9PKQ1.180904.001 means which of android it is?

Tags: android

I have made system update on my Redmi Note 5. Before system update  it has Android version 7.2. Now after I do system update it is showing MIUI version 11.0.5.0 and Android Version 9PKQ1.180904.001. I do not understand what is this android version indicates, is it android version 7 or 8 or 9 or 10? I did not understand. Now I want to update my android version on RedMi Note 5 to Android 10, is it possible?

Comment: This does not look like a programming question and might be better suited for android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It is not a version but an ID. Basically, Android provides Build class in android.os package in which there are numbers of static properties and static classes provided related to OS info, there "**ID**" is the property you are looking for.

So, if you are a normal Android user, this does not need your concern.